# Getting null when setting Bitmap on Android Studio

Tags: android, bitmap

I am new to Android development and I am currently working with Bitmap, I am trying to set a bitmap from a filepath of my device, however every time I debug it, it is still null, I have already searched for similar questions and I do what some people suggest but it is still not working, can anyone give me a clue of what am I doing wrong?

```
private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

private ImageButton buttonChoose;
private Button buttonUpload;
private Button buttonView;

private ImageView imageView;

private Bitmap bitmap;

private Uri filePath;



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        Toast.makeText(this,filePath.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        try {

            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

 private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
```

When debugging from this line:

```
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

it keeps in Null, and I can't continue with the app.

this is the debugging screenshot
[image]

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, since my Images were all in SD card, I had to add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and that is why I could not get the Bitmap correct. Probably a newbie error but well, I am just starting, thanks to those who took their time to help me, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String path;
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}, null, null, null);
if(cursor.moveToFIrst()){
    path=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close;

    //get bitmap from path;
    // you can also check whether the file exists and can be read here(not necessary).If you do that try to use DocumentFile
    bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
}
```

Comment: in this case, it is Cursor that stays null :/

Comment: You've put a toast to display filePath. Can you tell what it shows?

Comment: Actually I just used it to show what the filepath was, however, the app crashes before it can be shown, so is just useless.

Comment: So your ap crashes? You never mentioned it. Considering that you have a try catch its nothing to do with the bitmap. What does the crash log shows? And again I saw two methods with the same signature  showFileChooser()

Comment: Sorry about the double method, I edited it, when I was selecting the code for the question I copied it twice.
Getting back to the problem, My app is about uploading an image to a server, I select the image from my gallery and then I upload it, so, in the process of getting the filepath and converting the image to a Bitmap, I see that bitmap is getting null, not sure why, and if Bitmap is null, it can not continue with the process of uploading because  it crashes. So hopefully if the null problem is solved, it won't crash anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Please make below changes in your onActivityResult() method and try,

Hope it will work.

```
   try 
   {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, where do I declare imgDecodableString? I tried as a String field, but the Exception says that is never thrown in the correponding try block, and cannot test it yet